# Chat connection doesn't work

Tags: java, chat

So I am trying to make a simple chat client but somehow the connection doesn't work. Can you help me? This is what i wrote:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class game implements ActionListener{
    JTextArea incoming;
    JTextField outgoing;
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        game g = new game();
        g.go();

    }public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat");
        JButton sendB = new JButton("Send");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);

        incoming.setLineWrap(true);
        incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        incoming.setEditable(false);

            JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(incoming);
            s.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            s.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);     

        outgoing = new JTextField(25);
        sendB.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(s);
        mainPanel.add(outgoing);
        mainPanel.add(sendB);
        setUpnetworking();

        Thread readerThread = new Thread( new IncomingReader());
        readerThread.start();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);

    }public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
            writer.println(outgoing.getText());
            writer.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        outgoing.setText("");
        outgoing.requestFocus();
    }public void setUpnetworking(){
        try {
            sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000 );
            InputStreamReader streamreader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamreader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
        } catch (IOException exx) {
            exx.printStackTrace();
        }

    }public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            String message;
            try{
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println("read" + message);
                    incoming.append(message + "\n");
                }

                }catch (Exception exx){exx.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
 }
```

errors i got when i ran it:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at game.setUpnetworking(game.java:66)
    at game.go(game.java:45)
    at game.main(game.java:18)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at game$IncomingReader.run(game.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at game.actionPerformed(game.java:57)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i really don't know what's the problem :( can someone help me so i can build a working Chat Client? I use Eclipse.

Sorry for bad Englisch, I am from The Netherlands

Comment: This is just an error that says the host and port you're trying to connect to isn't listening.  Socket connections have two ends.  You can't talk to a server that isn't listening.  Is the server running and listening to port 5000?

Comment: How do i solve this?

Comment: Create and run a server?

Comment: I am a beginner so sorry, but how do i create a server? make a new class?

Answer (score 1):

For a chat app you need both backend and client-side solutions. 
To skip the part with server-side solution development you can use a ready backend and SDK provided by some platforms. That should save you a lot of time and effort and you will be able to concentrate on UI implementation. 
Here are some providers you might consider using:

- ConnectyCube
- Firebase
- Sendbird
- Layer

Here is also an [article](https://connectycube.com/2018/09/12/product-comparison-connectycube-vs-sendbird-vs-applozic-vs-layer/) comparing features provided by some of them.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to build a server. You would need to go through networking a bit. But just in case you need a server, I made one few months back. Run it separately. See if you can make it work.

https://github.com/DhavalKapil/ForwardingServer